# Converting string in array of Objects to an array of numbers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have an array of objects with some properties as string values, can someone help me to get array of numbers out it. Here is the array looks like.

```
  scores = [
               {
                  maxScore:"100"
                  obtainedScore:"79"
                  passed:"pass"
                  subject:"Maths"
               },
               {
                  maxScore:"100"
                  obtainedScore:"73"
                  passed:"pass"
                  subject:"Science"
               },
               {
                  maxScore:"100"
                  obtainedScore:"82"
                  passed:"pass"
                  subject:"English"
               }
           ]
```

i want **obtainedScore** and **maxScore** should be taken out from these objects  and place them in two different arrays

i tried this

```
for (var  i =0 ; i < score.length; i++)
{ 
   var marks[i] = parseInt(score[i].obtainedScore) ;
}
```

and i found NaN.

Comment: As this is a pretty straightforward iteration of an array of objects, I'm wondering what code you have tried.

Comment: i tried this for (var  i =0 ; i < score.length; i++){ var marks[i] = parseInt(score[i].obtainedScore; )} and i found NaN.

Comment: Put that code into your question.  You should always show us what you have tried.

Comment: @GavisiddaGadagi probably that you refer to it as `score` when the declaration is `scores`. have a look at my answer which has a working snippet based on your attempt.

Comment: Cud Accept the answer that world and close the question if u solved the issue..

Answer (score 1):

what about mapping a projection?

```
var maxScores = scores.map(score => parseInt(score.maxScore, 10))
var obtainedScores = scores.map(score => parseInt(score.obtainedScore, 10))
```

Comment: You need to convert from string to number.  I like the general simplicity of the approach though.

Comment: Oh, of course. completely overlooked that. if we assume the string represents a number, than it should be sufficient to add a 'parseInt'

Comment: It's a good practice to include the radix argument when using `parseInt()`.  Or you could just use `score => +score.maxScore`.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanx. wasn't aware of this. was just reading thru mdn. so actually old browsers before es5 used to read "010" as 8 bcoz of earlier default: 8. Strange!! I've  edited my answer as well. with the radix parameter as 10.

Answer (score 1):

1. **CORRECT ANSWER BASED ON YOUR ATTEMPT**:

   ```js
       var scores = [{
         maxScore: "100",
         obtainedScore: "79",
         passed: "pass",
         subject: "Maths"
       }, {
         maxScore: "100",
         obtainedScore: "73",
         passed: "pass",
         subject: "Science"
       }, {
         maxScore: "100",
         obtainedScore: "82",
         passed: "pass",
         subject: "English"
       }]
       var marks = [];
       for (var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
         marks[i] = parseInt(scores[i].obtainedScore, 10);
       }
       console.log(marks)
   ```
2. **MY SOLN** (from before you editted in your attempt)

```js
var scores = [{
      maxScore: "100",
      obtainedScore: "79",
      passed: "pass",
      subject: "Maths"
    }, {
      maxScore: "100",
      obtainedScore: "73",
      passed: "pass",
      subject: "Science"
    }, {
      maxScore: "100",
      obtainedScore: "82",
      passed: "pass",
      subject: "English"
    }]

    function decoupler(arr, prop) {
      return arr.map(function(item, index) {
        return parseInt(item[prop], 10);
      });
    }
    var arr1 = decoupler(scores, "maxScore");
    var arr2 = decoupler(scores, "obtainedScore");

    console.log(arr1);
    console.log(arr2);
```

Edit: Added radix parameter for `parseInt()` based on [comment by  jfriend00](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38949715/converting-string-in-array-of-objects-to-an-array-of-numbers#comment65254471_38949778).

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what you want the output to be but :

> i want obtainedScore and maxScore should be taken out from these
>   objects and place them in two different arrays

```
var arrScore = [],
        arrMax = [];

    scores.forEach(i => {
        arrScore.push(!isNaN(parseInt(i.obtainedScore)) ? parseInt(i.obtainedScore) : 0);
        arrMax.push(!isNaN(parseInt(i.maxScore)) ? parseInt(i.maxScore) : 0);
    });
```

Basically this creates two arrays `arrScore` which will contain each individual score value and `arrMax` which contains an array of the max scores.

Using the [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function we iterate the array and push the values into their respective arrays. Note for this we are also ensuring that the type is a valid integer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
scores = [
               {
                  maxScore:"100",
                  obtainedScore:"79",
                  passed:"pass",
                  subject:"Maths"
               },
               {
                  maxScore:"100",
                  obtainedScore:"73",
                  passed:"pass",
                  subject:"Science"
               },
               {
                  maxScore:"100",
                  obtainedScore:"82",
                  passed:"pass",
                  subject:"English"
               }
           ];
           maxScoreArray = new Array();
           obtainedScoreArray = new Array();

           for (var i = scores.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            maxScoreArray.push(Number(scores[i].maxScore));
            obtainedScoreArray.push(Number(scores[i].obtainedScore));
           }

           console.log(maxScoreArray);
           console.log(obtainedScoreArray);
```